# GUID in Java vs Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I want to use GUID in Oracle database table as primary key.but I checked there are options to generate GUID in Java also.So my doubt is which one is to use Oracle based GUID generation or Java based GUID generation.Which is good for  performance and standards?.

***Oracle Based : ***

```
select sys_guid() from dual;
```

***Java Based : ***

```
 UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
 return uuid.toString();
```

Comment: In general, let Oracle DBMS does *its own work* (i.e. creating *primary keys* for its own tables) and Client (Java) its own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an system where most code runs in Java and only pure SQL statements are executed in Oracle, then it will be more convenient to generate the primary key in Java.

If you have a lot of stored procedures, then you'll want to do it in Oracle.

If you have a mixture of both, the good thing about GUID is that you can generate them in both places and don't need to care about duplicates.

Performance wise, the GUID generation will hardly be relevant. The performance of database application is usually dominated by disk IO and the network round trips between Java (or a similar environment) and the database.